# How to solve ATI Radeon 7670M/ Intel HD Switchable Graphics recurring BSOD error?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, amd-radeon, sony-vaio, switchable-graphics

I recently bought a VAIO E Series laptop with an ATI Radeon 7670M and Intel HD Switchable Graphics. Around about one month ago, my computer started shutting down with **atikmpag.sys** blue screen error and the frequency of the errors kept on increasing with time. I am really worried about my VGA Adapter and whether or not it's gone bad. It's a 3 month old laptop!

I searched on Google about **atikmpag.sys** BSOD and most of them suggested that my driver probably needs to be updated. I searched the Sony website and also the ATI website, I did have the latest drivers installed. Yet, I uninstalled the driver and installed it back again. But blue screens just keep coming back again and again. It generally happens more frequently when I have a video running and have paused it to do something else.

I hope it's a driver issue!

**Edit:**
Error Code - 0x00000116

**Edit 2:**
Reinstalled Windows. Installed all the drivers again. Doesn't help.

Comment: Is there a bios update available for that model on the Sony website? If so install that, then re-install both video drivers.

Comment: I checked in the support section of the Product. All the drivers and patches are dated _12-Jun-2012_ which is a month before I bought the computer. So no updates.

Comment: Month is close, double check the versions to be sure they were installed at time of purchase.

Comment: I did reinstall but still the same problem. So now as a temporary solution I have uninstalled the AMD Switchable Graphics driver and am running the computer on just Intel HD Graphics, which I must say is pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a driver issue. After upgrading to Windows 8, I saw that there was a new AMD Graphics Driver for Windows 8. Solved my problem since I installed it. [This](http://www.sony.co.in/support/download/523245/product/sve14a15fn) is the driver.